# Using a Search Bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to add a search bar to my project, which I call the server passing as parameters words entered into the search bar.

All the examples I have found look on a TableView that contains data on which search is made but this is not what I want.

I thought of doing with a TextField but would like to know first if I could do with a SearchBar.

ps: sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here If you get all the data from the server using Web Services then here no meaning to use searchbar. you can do same thing with the textField also.

But if if you want it to look as search bar then you can use the photoshop designed UI. and validate text filed as search-bar.